# Why selecting a single attribute returns less rows than selecting all columns in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**The tables created and the queries made are not the primary focus of this question, what confuses me is that why the first query and the second query returns different numbers of rows**

```
drop table Reserves;
drop table Sailors;
drop table Boats;

create table Sailors (
    sid      char(1) not null,
    sname    char(1) not null,
    rating   int,
    age      int not null,
    primary key (sid)
);

create table Boats (
    bid      char(1) not null,
    bname    char(1) not null,
    color    varchar(5),
    primary key (bid)
);

create table Reserves (
    sid      char(1) not null,
    bid      char(1) not null,
    rdate    int not null,
    primary key (sid, bid, rdate),
    foreign key (sid) references Sailors(sid)
        on delete cascade,
    foreign key (bid) references Boats(bid)
        on delete cascade
);


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Insert values

insert into Sailors values ('1', 'q', 90, 24);
insert into Sailors values ('0', 's', 60, 22);
insert into Sailors values ('2', 'd', 80, 20);
insert into Sailors values ('3', 'w', 70, 18);
insert into Sailors values ('4', 'a', 60, 19);
insert into Sailors values ('5', 'l', 80, 17);
insert into Sailors values ('6', 'o', 90, 18);
insert into Sailors values ('7', 'q', 70, 20);
insert into Sailors values ('8', 'd', 60, 16);
insert into Sailors values ('9', 'i', 80, 22);

insert into Boats values ('0', 'U', 'red');
insert into Boats values ('1', 'P', 'red');
insert into Boats values ('2', 'Q', 'blue');
insert into Boats values ('3', 'C', 'green');
insert into Boats values ('4', 'L', 'blue');
insert into Boats values ('5', 'O', 'blue');
insert into Boats values ('6', 'A', 'red');
insert into Boats values ('7', 'C', 'red');
insert into Boats values ('8', 'Y', 'green');
insert into Boats values ('9', 'N', 'blue');

insert into Reserves values ('0', '0', 3);
insert into Reserves values ('0', '1', 2);
insert into Reserves values ('0', '2', 1);
insert into Reserves values ('0', '2', 3);
insert into Reserves values ('1', '0', 4);
insert into Reserves values ('3', '2', 2);
insert into Reserves values ('4', '0', 3);
insert into Reserves values ('4', '0', 1);
insert into Reserves values ('4', '1', 3);
insert into Reserves values ('4', '6', 4);
insert into Reserves values ('4', '7', 1);
insert into Reserves values ('5', '8', 2);
insert into Reserves values ('5', '9', 2);
insert into Reserves values ('7', '4', 4);
insert into Reserves values ('7', '5', 1);
insert into Reserves values ('8', '3', 2);
insert into Reserves values ('9', '3', 3);
insert into Reserves values ('9', '0', 1);
insert into Reserves values ('9', '6', 1);
insert into Reserves values ('9', '8', 2);

commit;


select *
from Sailors join Boats on color='red' natural left outer join Reserves
where rdate is null;

select sid
from Sailors join Boats on color='red' natural left outer join Reserves
where rdate is null;
```

I want to find the sid of the sailors who have not ordered all the red boats, the first query above returns the correct rows I am expecting, nonethless the second query returns only rows with sid=2 and sid=6, despite the two queries are identical. sailors with sid 2 and 6 are the only sailors who have not booked any boat.

Comment: I think the first query is returning the records you want more by luck than anything else - as the SQL as written is pretty meaningless. When you say "sailors who have not ordered all the red boats" do you mean sailors who have no reservations for a red boat or sailors who have any reservations that are not for a red boat?

Comment: Side observation: in SAILORS you have a column for AGE.  But 'age' is always changing.  Instead of trying to store the ever-changing 'age' of something/someone, store the origination/birth date as DATE. Then you can always accurately calculate the age by simply subtracting birth_date from sysdate.

Comment: @NickW - I haven't checked the queries yet; I assume you are right. But even then, the question stands. The two queries, if incorrect, should both produce the same number of rows in the output, even if the output is wrong. The OP asks why that is not the case.

Comment: @mathguy Thx, this is the exact question I am asking, the tables created and the queries written above are definitely not practical, but I am more curious about why the second query only returns rows with sid=2 and sid=6, while the first query returns all rows with null rdate column

Comment: @NickW,  because there are multiple red boats, my goal is to find either sailors who have no reservations at all, or who have reservations but have not reserved all the red boats.

Comment: One other point - you're using an ambiguous column reference to `sid`, which exists in two of the tables being joined. I'm wondering if (instead of barfing on the unqualified column name, it's picking one for you, and perhaps on the wrong side of the join? What happens if you do, for the last query, `select Sailors.sid` instead of `select sid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this looks like a **bug** in Oracle's implementation of `natural [...] join`. I will do some testing to see if it affects inner joins too.

Instead of `natural` join, one can use the syntax `left|right|inner join USING(...)` and giving the list of column names in the `using` clause. The list of columns should be the list of **ALL** columns that have the same name in the two members of the join.

Very simple experimentation with the data you provided (+1 even for that alone) shows that the results are the same as if we had written `using(sid, bid)` in the first query, but only `using(sid)` in the second. If in either query - regardless of what it selects, whether `*` or `sid` - you use the `using` syntax, you get the same number of rows in the output as either your first or your second query, depending on **what** you put in the `using` clause.

So, what Oracle does for the second query is simply wrong. I can only speculate, but I believe Oracle looks at the `SELECT` clause first, and perhaps at other clauses, to see what ***columns*** it needs to retrieve from each table. (For example, this tells the optimizer what indexes it could use, etc.) And at this step, Oracle decides - in your second query - that it doesn't need `bid`. Then when it translates "natural" join to its own internal code, it doesn't throw in `bid` as a join column. Which is wrong - and which is why I called this a "bug".

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Others have commented that both queries are "wrong" in that they do not solve the problem you were trying to solve. That may be entirely true. I didn't even look at your problem specification; here I am answering your question, which is valid regardless of the problem - which is, why do the two queries produce different numbers of rows. Even if they are "wrong" for your use case, they should essentially give "the same" wrong answer, not "different" wrong answers. That is the only thing I discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the query is ... errr... not correct

For example it gives you sailors with sid = 0 and sid = 1. These sailors bought red boats

This is SQL you need to display sailors that did not buy a red boat.

```
select sl.* 
  from Sailors sl
 where not exists (select 1
                     from Reserves rs
                     join Boats bs on rs.bid = bs.bid
                    where bs.color = 'red' and rs.sid = sl.sid);
```

Answer (score 0):

These 2 queries will give you what you asked for in your last comment. I've UNION'd them together to give you a single list of SIDs but obviously you can run them independently if you want 22 separate lists.

```
-- Sailors with no reservations
select s.sid
from sailors s
where s.sid not in (
    select sid from reserves)
union
-- Sailors with reservations but not of red boats
select s.sid
from sailors s
where s.sid not in (
Select distinct r.sid
from reserves r
inner join boats b on r.bid = b.bid
where b.color = 'red');
```